# Efficiently generating rankings from (in)equalities

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, directed-graph, inequality

I have a bunch of constraints, each consisting of two symbols and a comparison operator: `<`, `<=`, `!=`, `==`, `>=`, or `>`. So, for example:

```
A <= B
C >= B
A != C
C == D
D > E
```

I want to be able to do three things:

1. First, I want to check if there are any inconsistencies. So, for example, if I have `A > B`, `B > C`, and `A == C`, there's an inconsistency, as `A` must be both equal to `C` and greater than it.
2. I want to be able to query any two symbols, and get back the feasible relative ordering(s) between them. So for example `query(A, C)` should return `{<}` (a set consisting of a single element: less than), and `query(B, E)` should return `{<, =, >}`.
3. I want to be able to add a constraint (this could also add (an) additional symbol(s), for example adding `F == G` to the above example).

Queries are more common than adding constraints.

I've already come up with a method that works if you do not have any `!=` constraints:

1. Translate every constraint into one(s) that only use(s) `<` or `<=` (So: `X == Y` turns into `X <= Y` and `Y <= X`, `X > Y` turns into `Y < X`, etc.).
2. Build a directed graph with the symbols, using the constraints as edges.
3. For all cycles in the graph, if the cycle includes at least one `<` edge, there is a contradiction.

To `query(X, Y)`:

1. Find any path between `X` and `Y`.

   - If there is no such path, the result of this part is `{<, =, >}`.
   - If the path contains at least one `<`, the result of this part is `{<}`.
   - Otherwise, the result of this part is `{<, =}`.
2. Find any path between `Y` and `X`

   - If there is no such path, the result of this part is `{<, =, >}`.
   - If the path contains at least one `<`, the result of this part is `{>}`.
   - Otherwise, the result of this part is `{=, >}`.
3. The result is the union of the above two results.

(Obviously, I can cache the queries, at least until I add another constraint)

I can extend this to include `!=`, but then it becomes exponentially slower w.r.t. the number of constraints that use `!=`. (Keep a set of graphs instead of one. Every time you add a constraint with `!=`, for each graph in the set replace it with two copies, one where the constraint to be added is `<`, one where it is `>`. Any time one produces a contradiction, discard it. If the set of graphs is empty, there is a contradiction. On a query, check all graphs, unioning the answers together.)

So, is there a more efficient way to solve this problem? Or is it going to be exponential-time worst case regardless?

I am aware that I could use a SAT solver for this, but it seems a mite overkill, to put it mildly, especially as I cannot see it ever exceeding 100 constraints, with 10 being more typical.

(For those interested in what this came out of, I am working on a toy programming language and became interested in the idea of making custom infix operators, where priority is decided by relation to existing operators instead of a straight numerical value (which has issues when you want to add a new operator with higher priority than `A` but lower than `B`, but there is no gap between the two. `!=` is not strictly required for that problem, but I became interested in how one would include it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some lovely mathematics to the effect that, unless you can prove that A <= B and B <= A using reflexivity and transitivity, there exists a model where A != B. The forced equality classes on variables correspond one-to-one with the strongly connected components of the graph of <=-related variables (where A = B induces A <= B and B <= A).

In total, the algorithm for determining feasibility is to extract all of the <= constraints (where A < B induces A <= B, and A = B induces A <= B and B <= A, and A != B induces nothing), find strong components in the directed graph, then verify, for every A < B and A != B, that A and B lie in different strong components. To query, add each possibility in turn and check feasibility.